# .net core publicacion de sitios

Tags: .net

net core 2.2.301 en mi linux y ya he desarrollando un aplicación MVC en visual estudio la he subido sin publicar al server y usando el comando dotnet run --urls "http://0.0.0.0:5000" la he puesto a funcionar pero lo que no he logrado es publicarla en visual estudio para después pasarla al servidor y ponerla que se quede permanente esa parte no la he logrado he publicado y visual me ha generado las .dll pero no lo puedo hacer funcionar no se si me puedan ayudar o darme un tutorial de .net core para publicar paginas web usando .net core
gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner tu sitio como un demonio de Linux usando "systemd".

Para ello deberás hacer lo siguiente:

1. Publica tu sitio desde el Visual Studio como lo estas haciendo.
2. Identifica el directorio con todos los archivos de publicación, dlls, configs, views, css, etc.
3. Crea un archivo de texto en Linux llamado "tusitio.service" ("tusitio" lo podes reemplazar con el nombre que quieras o mas acorde a tu web)
4. Dentro de ese archivo pega el siguiente código que está a continuación y adaptalo a tus directorios, nombres de dlls, etc. (esto es solo un ejemplo)

```
[Unit]
Description=Servicio de tusitio - ASP.NET MVC

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/publicacion/tusitio
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /publicacion/tusitio/tusitio.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=tusitio_servicio
User=root
TimeoutStopSec=30
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

WorkingDirectory: es donde tienes el directorio con todos los archivos de publicación
ExecStart: debes poner el directorio del comando dotnet, un espacio y el path exacto de donde se encuentra tu dll del sitio.

5. Guarda los cambios y copia el archivo creado de la siguiente forma desde la linea de comandos

```
sudo cp tusitio.service /etc/systemd/system/
```

6. Una vez copiado, deberás ejecutar los siguientes comandos

```
sudo systemctl enable tuservicio.service
sudo systemctl start tuservicio.service
```

LISTO! ya tienes tu servicio/demonio funcionando con tu sitio web. Para ver el estado del servicio puedes ejecutar

```
sudo systemctl status tuservicio.service
```

Para detener tu servicio puedes ejecutar

```
sudo systemctl stop tuservicio.service
```